# Was my question asking for an explanation of a strange CSS behavior poor?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked this question yesterday: [Changing the display attribute nullifies opacity transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280937/changing-the-display-attribute-nullifies-opacity-transitions)

At a quick glance, it is easy to mistake it for the common problem people have trying to use `transition` on the `display` attribute, about which there are plenty of questions on SO already (and would thus make it a duplicate).

I originally did not include code snippets in my question and only linked to an external site (JSFiddle). I see why that is wrong (although I don't remember external links being that frowned upon around two years ago when I was active on SO), but I don't think that makes it a bad question. It was easily remedied with an edit.

I thought the question was intriguing, as the code was extremely simple but I could not understand the behavior. I understand that most people who ask this type of questions are [help vampires](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem). However, I think I made it rather clear that I wanted an explanation of the phenomenon rather than help with a workaround.

It is possible that the downvotes were merely due to my external links instead of code snippets or a misunderstanding of the question (thinking it was the aforementioned duplicate), but I am not sure whether that is the case or not.

Was my question bad? Inherently bad, or merely poorly researched? Should I have given a more detailed explanation of *why* I found the behavior unintuitive and the question intriguing?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design. Your question seems to me like a "why" question.

Comment: Not exactly seeing any immediate problems with the question.  It seems a lot better than most we get.  You've cleaned up some of the initial problems with it, at least.

Comment: Note however that just because you've cleaned up the question, doesn't mean the people who initially voted on it will retract their votes, nor does it mean future visitors will find it to be of sufficient quality/usefulness to up vote it. It's very important that posts start out high quality to begin with, considering that it's most likely to receive votes during it's initial posting rather than later on.

Comment: Yeah I can't see nothing here that would justify downvoting.  Now... the original version of the question is a very different deal. It is possible you got 3 downvotes because people didn't like your link, and they just never saw your question after you made it better

Comment: I know nothing about the tech, but you have a few comments that seem to indicate that potential answerers think that the basis for your question is fundamentally flawed. That could lead people to think that the question is uninteresting, poorly researched, not worth answering, and/or not a useful post to keep around on the site.

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain I don't think it's a "why"-question. That type of question is not necessarily answerable with a direct reference to language specification. It is a lack of understanding of the behavior of a piece of code, which I can admit could be further explored before made into a question on SO.

Comment: Unless the erroneous assumption that prompted the question seems like a mistake that other people are going to make too, I usually just find such a question a frustrating experience, personally.

Comment: @KevinB Yes I understand that, and I mentioned it too in this question, in fact.

Comment: @JoshCaswell as I understood it, they mistook it for the would-be duplicate question, which is similarly phrased. I probably did a poor job making sure that the question wouldn't be mistaken for that one.

Comment: That seems like the most likely explanation to me. /shrug

Comment: Without the initial mistakes, this would have been an "even" question

Comment: @AntoinePelletier what is an "even" question?

Comment: No upvotes, no downvotes, just an OK question, like there's millions

Comment: Regarding JSFiddle, their license is incompatible with Stack Overflow so we can't (or at least shouldn't) edit in code from their into a question for the OP. Only the original author would have the right to put the code here so that wasn't an edit any of the voters could have made themselves. (The form would normally warn you about having the fiddle links without the accompanying code but your question did have some inline code already.)

Answer (score 11):

CSS answerer who specializes in answering "why does this behave this way?" questions here.

> Was my question bad?

Nah.

> Inherently bad, or merely poorly researched?

Answers to your question exist on the site (see the duplicate question that your question has been linked to), but I'm not sure how eager I would be to call it poorly researched. It certainly isn't inherently bad, because to me at least it's unreasonable to expect anyone to *intuitively* understand why the `display` property messes with transitions the way it does, let alone know about the word "reflow" (that's where expert answers come in...).

The best I could offer in terms of research is a cursory read through either MDN or even the CSS spec on w3.org. The former is much more accessible to developers but doesn't always touch on technical details better explained in the spec. But either way it is best to search through them, see what you can make of them, and explain what you found, or didn't find.

> Should I have given a more detailed explanation of why I found the behavior unintuitive and the question intriguing?

Perhaps. We like to see that question askers understand what they're getting into and have put some thought and consideration into the problem they are solving or the question they are asking (if they're not actually trying to solve a problem, just understanding how something works).

You have already addressed the main editorial issue with your question that was the fiddle links without any included code. I don't see anything else that sticks out like a sore thumb. Just downvotes that have not been revisited since your edits (well, one was, which is a start!).